# In python, how do i create a program that simply gives the list position of whatever is in my list?

Tags: python, list

For example, lets say I have a list
example=[A,B,C,D]

How do I return the value of the position? So for A, I would want a returned value of 0. B would be 1, C would be 2, D would be 3.

Comment: 90% of the time, when you _think_ you want to do this, what you _actually_ wanted was to have a `dict` mapping values to numbers, not a `list` that you have to search through over and over.

Comment: Do you just need the `index` positions like 0,1,2,3 ? or you want the elements of the `example` and the `index` ? I am not so sure if I understand what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for .index() of a list object

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].index('c') # 2
```